# I want to figure out variance over time

Tags: math, mathematica-8

I have some data set i collected. I was asked to plot variance and can i plot variance over time. I have 100 data for 20 seconds.Is it possible to plot variance over time or only one variance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to plot variance over time.  For example, you can find the variance of data points 0 to 10, then 1 to 11, then 2 to 12... and then plot that against 0, 1, 2...

Comment: i didnt get a little part why 0-10,1-11; is it like 0-10 ->0,11-20->2 like that ?

Comment: That's another possibility.  You could have 10 time segments 0-10, 11-20, 21-30 ... that map to 0, 1, 2..., or you could have 100 time segments 0-10, 1-11, 2-12... that map to 0,1,2 ... Depending on what this is for, either choice is could be acceptable.

Comment: Its for RF signal and i think 0-10, 11-20, 21-30 will be okay thanks

Comment: You're welcome!  Don't forget to accept the answer if this solved your problem.